# onclick error calling Xquery function

Tags: xml, xpath, xhtml, xquery, exist-db

i'm trying to call a function with parameters, send an id and return the url of a photo, the idea is to show the photo of the element when you click on a button, the problem is that i can't call the funcion i swear that i try it, and googled it, but i simply can't :P

here's the code of the function and the declaration

xquery version "1.0";

declare namespace local = "local";
declare option exist:serialize "method=xhtml media-type=text/html";

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare namespace local = "local";
declare option exist:serialize "method=xhtml media-type=text/html";


    declare function local:showPhoto($id as xs:decimal?)AS xs:string?
    {
    for $dir in doc("pubs.xml")//dir
    where  id= $dir/id
    return $dir/photo/text();
    };
```

and here's the table and the code to call it, sure that if you know a better way to do it just tell me :P (of course i'm a little noob with this so i'm sure that you can tell me a better way to do it)

```
<table id="pubs" border="1">
        { 
        for $directorio in doc("/db/Ocio/pubs.xml")//dir
        order by $dir/name
        return
            <tr>
            <td>{$dir/name/text()}</td>
            <td><a href="{$dir/web/text()}">Web url</a></td>
            <td><input onclick="{local:showPhoto($dir/id)" type="button" value="MOAR INFO"></input></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

maybe there's an error here but it's cause i translated the code to english, when i execute ir this is the error:

XPDY0002 : undefined context sequence for...

not sure what to do so i ask it, Thank you very much in advance :D :D :D

X-mas btw :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two issues are obvious**:

1. `AS xs:string?`  -- I think that XQuery (as XPath) is case-sensitive. Therefore, `AS` should raise an error, because the syntactically legal token is `as`.
2. The body of the function:

.

```
for $dir in doc("pubs.xml")//dir
    where  id= $dir/id
    return $dir/photo/text();
```

There is no initial context node defined for a function in XQuery (and in XSLT). Therefore, any relative XPath expression is undefined. This is the case with `id`  -- the child `id` of what?

**The solution is** that an absolute expression must be used instead -- such as:

```
 $someParam/id
```

Comment: i Changed it but the error is still when i call the funcion, i explain myself: i create the function, launch the webApp and all is OK, the problem is when i call it, maybe i don't know how to call it :S but i tried to call a simple function, i googled how to call it and the error is the same, i read something about the namespace, but i declared too (as i putted in the code) and same error. By the other hand thank you so much for your solution, i solved that errors :3

Comment: just forget it, it works, don't disturb you anymore :P thank you so much again ^^